# determine if a given IP address is in a specific subnet

Tags: networking, subnet, rfc

Assuming there is a given ip address, how to determine if it is in a specific subnet with mask?

`(ip & mask == subnet & mask)` and `(ip & mask == subnet)`, which is better?

Comment: what's the question here? Subnet + mask is better than just the subnet, because without the mask you don't know how big the subnet is ..

Comment: I also have no idea who would +1 this question tbh ...